# resizing of dhtmlxLayout

Tags: layout, dhtmlx

Using 2U pattern of dhtmlxLayout, when I resize the window, layout is not auto fit as for the window size. How to make responsive layout, is there any API available to auto adjust the layout on resize of window(without browser refresh) ?

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
…
layout = new dhtmlXLayoutObject("container","2U");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use it in a [fullscreen init](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxLayout/samples/01_init/03_fullscreen.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the fixSize(false,false) method,you can able to resize the item horizontally and vertically. setAutosize("b;c","a;c") method to change the layout's items to adjust automatically to the dimension changes of the layout.